# Destructure JS object with similar children

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, object-destructuring

I have the following setup, but keep getting the error: `Argument name clash`. How can I destructure this and still maintain the value?

```
const Message = ({message: { user, text }, nickname}, {quest: { user, text }, nickname} ) =>{
```

Comment: Don't try to destructure multiple things into the same variable?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rename one of the "clashing" variables, like this:

```js
const func = ({ a }, { a: b }) => {
  console.log(a, b);
}

const obj = { a: 'foo' };
func(obj, obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the params to resolve the variable name conflicts like:

```
const Message = ({
   message: {
      user: message_user,
      text: message_text
   },
   nickname: message_nickname
}, {
   quest: {
      user: quest_user,
      text: quest_text
   },
   nickname: quest_nickname
}) => {

}
```

Or, you can also try this if you want to use same variable names, but you cannot work with all at the same time:

```
const Message = (param1, param2) => {
   let { message, nickname } = param1, quest;
   let { user, text } = message;
   // Do you stuff realed to message, user, text & nickname

   ({ quest, nickname } = param2);
   ({ user, text } = quest);
   // Do you stuff realed to quest, user, text & nickname
}
```

Comment: still says user is undefined

Comment: Could you please share an example of the code that you tied an it returns undefined. You can an add simple object to destructure for the demo purpose.